# Batching a query from a linked Oracle database in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2016, ssms

Working to compare and older Oracle database with a newer updated version to check that all documents have migrated correctly. 1=1 and 2=2.
The database is very large ~25,000,000 rows. So I want to be able to run this in batches of ~1,000,000 in order to make it more manageable.

The code looks at a list of all documents in the Oracle server. Finds the full path for all of these documents and stores it in CTE S
The code also finds the full path for the Microsoft database and stores it in CTE P.

These two CTE's are then joined and compared to check that they have the same count.

I can easily limit the newer code by limiting the dataID's but this doesn't seem to work for the oracle code.

```
with P (id, path) as ( 
select DTreeCore.ParentID, cast (Name as varchar(max))
  from CS16PDDB.LIVELINKPD.DTreeCore with (NOLOCK)
union all 
select ParentID, cast (Name + ':' + P.path as varchar(max))
   from CS16PDDB.LIVELINKPD.DTreeCore join P
   on DataID = P.id or DataID = - P.id
),
S (id, path) as (
SELECT ID, PATH from OPENQUERY(CS,'
select
concat(''Enterprise'',SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(TRIM(REPLACE(Name,'':'',''- 
'')),'':'')) as path,
dtc.DataID as id,dtc.Name,dtc.ParentID
from DTreeCore dtc
where Subtype = 144 AND dataID < 5000 --Here should work
connect by prior DataID=ParentID start with DataID = 2000
')
)
select count (P.path), count(S.path) from P
left join S ON P.path = S.path
where P.id = -1
```

I've tried a few different things. Rownum's seem to be generated after the full test has been done so i cant filter on those. I tried FETCH FIRST but also struggled there.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.